# Convertir un texto "Docs/Bim/Dex" a treeview

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Es posible convertir una simple direccion "Docs/Bim/Dex" a un elemento TreeView.

Ejemplo:

> Docs/Bim/Dex

```
Docs
 |
 + Bim
   |
   + Dex
```

Se me ha ocurrido utilizar `textbox1.text.split("/")`, pero so se como aplicarlo despues, supongo que con un for o un while, pero no se como empezar